# PyTorch Lightning - Display metrics after validation epoch

Tags: python, pytorch-lightning

I've implemented `validation_epoch_end` to produce and log metrics, and when I run `trainer.validate`, the metrics appear in my notebook.

However, when I run `trainer.fit`, only the training metrics appear; not the validation ones.

The validation step is still being run (because the validation code calls a `print` statement, which *does* appear), but the validation metrics don't appear, even though they're logged.  Or, if they do appear, the next epoch immediately erases them, so that I can't see them.

(Likewise, tensorboard sees the validation metrics)

How can I see the validation epoch end metrics in a notebook, as each epoch occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following. Let's say you have the following `LightningModule`:

```py
class MNISTModel(LightningModule):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.l1 = torch.nn.Linear(28 * 28, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        return torch.relu(self.l1(x.view(x.size(0), -1)))

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_nb):
        x, y = batch
        loss = F.cross_entropy(self(x), y)
        # prog_bar=True will display the value on the progress bar statically for the last complete train epoch
        self.log("train_loss", loss, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)

        return loss

    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_nb):
        x, y = batch
        loss = F.cross_entropy(self(x), y)
        # prog_bar=True will display the value on the progress bar statically for the last complete validation epoch
        self.log("val_loss", loss, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)

        return loss

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        return torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=0.02)
```

The trick is to use `prog_bar=True` in combination with `on_step` and `on_epoch` depending on when you want the update on the progress bar. So, in this case, when training:

```
# Train the model ⚡
trainer.fit(mnist_model, MNIST_dm)
```

you will see:

```bash
Epoch 4: 100% -------------------------- 939/939 [00:09<00:00, 94.51it/s, loss=0.636, v_num=4, val_loss=0.743, train_loss=0.726]
```

Where `loss` will be updating each batch as it is the step loss. However, `val_loss` and `train_loss` will be static values that will only change after each validation or train epoch respectively.

Comment: Works! Why do I need to specify `prog_bar=True` for `validation_step` but not for `training_step`? Also, bizarrely, now that I added `prog_bar=True`, my existing `print` statements show up as well - why is that?

Comment: If you don't set `prog_bar=True` for `training_step` you will only see the batch loss, i.e. `loss`. Setting `prog_bar=True`, `train_loss` will also appear, which is the epoch_loss